# Can one play multiplayer games on Steam locally, each logging in to their own account?

Tags: steam, controllers

I've played Injustice 2 with my friend on my their Xbox. Each player can login from their account, in order to track their progress.

Does Steam support this feature, especially when playing multiplayer games with Steam controllers?

Comment: Do you mean the players playing multiplayer together on different systems over LAN using a single copy of the game?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Arqade! Can you clarify the specifics on how you intend to play together on Steam? For example, split-screen, LAN, or online game?

Comment: Sounds like local multiplayer but with 'login' for the second player to access their account, track their stats, use their loadouts etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Steam enables such feature, unless the game itself has a account system itself (such as some MMORPGs)